# Powershell maximum 250

Tags: powershell

I have problem, I make an API Call with Powershell to get an object with the user information.

```
function Get-Companies {
$GetCompanies = @{
    Method      = "GET"
    ContentType = "application/json"
    URI         = "https...api/cm/companies"
}
$companies = Invoke-RestMethod @GetCompanies;
return $companies;}
```

When I want to access the object I get only 250 entries

```
$companies = Get-Companies
$companies.rows #Only 250 Entries (Should be more than 7,000)
```

Do you guys know why this is happening? I'm pretty new to Powershell, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that your rest API doesn't return paginated results?

Comment: As someone mentioned previous to this it is likely you are only getting a subset of the total results in your JSON response. What API are you trying to interact with - it’s likely there is documentation that will allow you to pass some something inside the request to filter results or expand.

Comment: When I print out the object without the ".row" I get all 7000 elements.